# Not getting static files with django & heroku deployment

Tags: django, heroku, gunicorn, django-static

I'm developing a webapp with Django 1.7 (project_name is "sonata") and the project layout from the "Two scoops of Django 1.6", so I have a 3-tier basic folder tree.

```
.
├── docs
├── requirements
├── scripts
└── sonata
    ├── person
    │   └── templatetags
    ├── registration
    ├── sonata
    │   └── settings
    ├── static
    │   ├── css
    │   │   └── images
    │   ├── fonts
    │   └── js
    ├── templates
    │   ├── personApp
    │   └── registrationApp
    └── utils
        └── templatetags
```

I have a problem when deploying on Heroku. I have achieved the deployment, but the static files are not being served to the browser.

I know I should force some way of serving the static files through the settings and have googled about. I've seen many ways and read about using Amazon services, but I'm looking for the easiest one, which will make the future production deployment easy as well with gUnicorn (I hope).

I tried modifying the settings file (further down, is the heroku.py one, which overrides the base.py) and changing values for STATIC_ROOT, STATICFILES_DIRS and adding the line:

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

I've tried as well running:

```
heroku run sonata/manage.py collectstatic
```

before doing

```
git push heroku master
```

but nothing happens, even checking with

```
heroku run ls sonata/assets
```

that the files are being copied.

Please, I would like some orientation for really understanding what I'm doing wrong and mending it.

When finding out about heroku and deployment I met also some sample ProcFiles which used a project_name.wsgi file and I don't know anything about it.

I could use use some help, because the more webs I read, the more confused I get. Please assume I know very little about deployments. A link would be useful, but it has to show newbie's material :-(

Thank you very much on advance.

**ProcFile:**

```
web: python sonata/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT --noreload
```

**heroku.py:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Heroku settings and globals."""

from __future__ import absolute_import

from .base import *

from os import environ

# TODO Warning! Heroku retrieve values as strings
# TODO we should check (only for Heroku) that 'True' and 'False' are respectively True and False 0, 
# or the equivalent ones, True and False
def get_env_setting(setting):
    """ Gets the environment variable or an Exception.
    This can be used, for example, for getting the SECRET_KEY and not having it hardcoded in the source code 
    Also for setting the active settings file for local development, heroku, production server, etc... """
    try:
        return environ[setting]
    except KeyError:
        error_msg = "Set the %s env variable" % setting
        raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)

########## HOST CONFIGURATION
# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/releases/1.5/#allowed-hosts-required-in-production
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
########## END HOST CONFIGURATION

########## EMAIL CONFIGURATION
# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#email-backend
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#email-host
EMAIL_HOST = environ.get('EMAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com')

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#email-host-password
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD', '')

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#email-host-user
EMAIL_HOST_USER = environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_USER', 'your_email@example.com')

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#email-port
EMAIL_PORT = environ.get('EMAIL_PORT', 587)

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#email-subject-prefix
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = '[%s] ' % SITE_NAME

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#email-use-tls
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#server-email
SERVER_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
########## END EMAIL CONFIGURATION

########## DATABASE CONFIGURATION
import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()
# DATABASES = {}
########## END DATABASE CONFIGURATION


########## CACHE CONFIGURATION
# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#caches
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
    }
}
########## END CACHE CONFIGURATION


########## SECRET CONFIGURATION
# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#secret-key
SECRET_KEY = get_env_setting('SECRET_KEY')
########## END SECRET CONFIGURATION
```

**base.py:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Common settings and globals."""

from os.path import abspath, basename, dirname, join, normpath
from sys import path


from os import environ

def get_env_setting(setting):
    """ Gets the environment variable or an Exception.
    This can be used, for example, for getting the SECRET_KEY and not having it hardcoded in the source code 
    Also for setting the active settings file for local development, heroku, production server, etc... """
    try:
        return environ[setting]
    except KeyError:
        error_msg = "Set the %s env variable" % setting
        raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)


########## PATH CONFIGURATION
# Absolute filesystem path to the Django project directory:
DJANGO_ROOT = dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__)))

# Absolute filesystem path to the top-level project folder:
SITE_ROOT = dirname(DJANGO_ROOT)

# Site name:
SITE_NAME = basename(DJANGO_ROOT)

# Add our project to our pythonpath, this way we don't need to type our project
# name in our dotted import paths:
path.append(DJANGO_ROOT)
########## END PATH CONFIGURATION


########## DEBUG CONFIGURATION
# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#debug
DEBUG = False

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-debug
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
########## END DEBUG CONFIGURATION


########## MANAGER CONFIGURATION
# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#admins
ADMINS = (
    ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#managers
MANAGERS = ADMINS
########## END MANAGER CONFIGURATION


########## DATABASE CONFIGURATION
# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#databases
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.',
        'NAME': '',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
########## END DATABASE CONFIGURATION


########## GENERAL CONFIGURATION
# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#time-zone
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Madrid'

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#language-code
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es-es'
DEFAULT_CHARSET = 'utf-8'

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#site-id
SITE_ID = 1

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#use-i18n
USE_I18N = True

LOCALE_PATHS = (# Idiomas disponibles en la aplicación
                SITE_ROOT + '/locale',
                )

LANGUAGES = (# Ruta donde buscar ficheros de idioma
                 ('es', 'Español'),
                 ('gl', 'Galego'),
                 ('en', 'English'),
                 ('it', 'Italiano'),
             )

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#use-l10n
USE_L10N = True

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#use-tz
USE_TZ = True
########## END GENERAL CONFIGURATION


########## MEDIA CONFIGURATION
# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#media-root
MEDIA_ROOT = normpath(join(SITE_ROOT, 'media'))

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#media-url
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
########## END MEDIA CONFIGURATION


########## STATIC FILE CONFIGURATION
# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#static-root
STATIC_ROOT = normpath(join(SITE_ROOT, 'assets'))

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#static-url
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    normpath(join(SITE_ROOT, 'static')),
)

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#staticfiles-finders
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
########## END STATIC FILE CONFIGURATION

########## LOGIN REDIRECTION
# The URL you'd like to redirect users to that aren't logged in
LOGIN_URL = '/registration/login/'
#########################################

########## LOGIN NOT REQUIRED
# Tuple of regular expressions that lists your exceptions to the default login required on every page.
LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS = (
 r'^registration/login\.html$',
 r'^admin/',
)
#########################################

########## SECRET CONFIGURATION
# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#secret-key
# Note: This key should only be used for development and testing.
SECRET_KEY = r"I am not going to show you my secret key, sorry"
########## END SECRET CONFIGURATION


########## SITE CONFIGURATION
# Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
########## END SITE CONFIGURATION


########## FIXTURE CONFIGURATION
# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-FIXTURE_DIRS
FIXTURE_DIRS = (
    normpath(join(SITE_ROOT, 'fixtures')),
)
########## END FIXTURE CONFIGURATION


########## TEMPLATE CONFIGURATION
# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-context-processors
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.core.context_processors.tz',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
)

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-loaders
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-dirs
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    normpath(join(SITE_ROOT, 'templates')),
    normpath(join(SITE_ROOT, 'templates/registration')),
    normpath(join(SITE_ROOT, 'templates/person')),
)
########## END TEMPLATE CONFIGURATION


########## MIDDLEWARE CONFIGURATION
# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#middleware-classes
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    # Default Django middleware.
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    # Custom middleware
    'sonata.settings.middleware.LoginRequiredMiddleware',
)
########## END MIDDLEWARE CONFIGURATION


########## URL CONFIGURATION
# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#root-urlconf
ROOT_URLCONF = '%s.urls' % SITE_NAME
########## END URL CONFIGURATION


########## APP CONFIGURATION
DJANGO_APPS = (
    # Default Django apps:
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # Useful template tags:
    # 'django.contrib.humanize',

    # Admin panel and documentation:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)

# Apps specific for this project go here.
LOCAL_APPS = (
    'person',
    'registration',
    'utils',
)

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#installed-apps
INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + LOCAL_APPS
########## END APP CONFIGURATION


########## LOGGING CONFIGURATION
# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#logging
# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
########## END LOGGING CONFIGURATION


########## WSGI CONFIGURATION
# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#wsgi-application
WSGI_APPLICATION = '%s.wsgi.application' % SITE_NAME
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it. I had to include the following lines in heroku.py:

**heroku.py**

```
# Important for Heroku
BASE_DIR = dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__)))

STATIC_ROOT = 'static' # Important for Heroku
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),  # Important for Heroku
)
```

I had to add some lines to wsgi.py for static files:

**wsgi.py**

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise

application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

and also change the Procfile:

**Procfile**

```
web: gunicorn --chdir sonata --log-file - sonata.wsgi:application
```

Answer (score 1):

The Procfile tells Heroku what processes it should start.  Without it, Heroku
has no way of starting the application.  But first of all, for a Python
application you need a `requirements.txt` file at the root of your repository.

I'm not familiar with *Two Scoops of Django* (I know about the book, but I've
never read it), so I'm not sure what that project layout is all about.  It's
not wrong for sure, but it seems overly complicated to me, especially for a
total beginner since it deviates somewhat from the “canonical” way of laying
out a Django project.  So I would really recommend that if you're just starting
out with Django to take a look and work through the
[official Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/) (the First Steps section on that page).

Now assuming your current layout, for Heroku you need two files in the root of
your repository (at the same level where the `docs`, `scripts` etc. directories
are): `Procfile` and `requirements.txt`.  Assuming your WSGI entry point is
in the `sonata/sonata` directory (it should be called `wsgi.py`), `Procfile`
should have something like this:

```
web: gunicorn sonata.sonata.wsgi --log-file -
```

Note that the `Procfile` you presented here should be able to run (assuming
Python path is correct), but you're using the development server which *should
not* be done in deployment environment.  That `gunicorn` thing in my `Procfile`
is a standard production quality Python WSGI application server and the `Procfile`
simply says run `gunicorn` with this application.

The `requirements.txt` file should have at least:

```
Django>=1.7
gunicorn
```

in it.  This file tells Heroku which Python packages to install with Pip (Python's
package manager).  In
this case the latest version of Django 1.7 branch and [Gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/).  It should also
list other Python dependencies your project has.  The presence of this file
is also what tells Heroku your application is a Python application.  You should
really carefully read the [Getting started with Django on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django)
guide as it has the basics covered and pointers to further reading.  I agree
that Heroku's documentation is a bit all over the place for a total beginner,
but if you take one step at a time and use Google for things that are unclear
to you, you should have a working setup relatively quickly.

As for static files, yes, you can do the thing with the `static()` function
in `urlpatterns` even if you're using Gunicorn instead of the development server
but only if `DEBUG = True` in the `settings.py`, which it should absolutely not
be in production!  If this is just a staging or a test, it's OK, but even then
the fundamental fact remains: Heroku is just an application server basically.
It is not meant for serving of any static files.  You can theoretically serve
them from Heroku with the `static()` trick but as soon as you do a new deployment
or as soon as the app restarts (which can and does happen frequently
for a number of reasons) *all* of your static files will be *gone*.  So, practically,
you *have to* host your static files somewhere else, be it S3 or something other.

You also have a possible mistake in how you set up the `static()` function, it
should be (if you also want to serve media files):

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) +\
               static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Again, this will work only for a short time until your app restarts for whatever
reason, at which point you'll have a broken app because all the static files
are gone.

Also note that you do not need to run `collectstatic` manually on Heroku.  It
will detect a Django application and run it automatically on deploy.  Even if
it didn't, you can't do it before you push your repository.  It's the other way
around, you first push and then `collectstatic` runs (you'll see it being run
automatically).

It seems to me you really have your head tied in a knot with this, so my advice
would be to take a step back.  Make a very simple vanilla Django app (by following
the tutorial I mentioned), and try deploying that to Heroku for which you should
follow their Django deployment basics I linked.  Even with that approach there
are possible caveats, but those are out of the scope of this question.  One step
at a time (go as far back as you need until you figure it out) and you'll be fine.

Comment: The fact is we're not beginners at Django but we never didn't deploy in Heroku before except from when we did when following "Getting started with Django", which we knew, but there was a completely different structure. We are coming back and read this carefully. About the collectstatic, I've seen people doing this in the ProcFile just before the runserver command with ";" in between. Don't know if that would be right with gUnicorn. I will try soon the next few days  (I have more tasks to do) and answer

Comment: @madtyn I think `collectstatic` was needed in the Procfile before, but not anymore. Now it's done automatically when you deploy. It's unrelated to Gunicorn part. What happens when you do `git push heroku master`?

Comment: It seems you're right, @NZP 
 
remote: -----> Preparing static assets
remote:        Running collectstatic...
remote:        99 static files copied to '/app/sonata/assets'.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm developing a webapp with Django 1.7 (project_name is "sonata") and
>   the project layout from the "Two scoops of Django 1.6", so I have a
>   3-tier basic folder tree.

The Two Scoops template that you are referring to is only for 1.6, you should not use it for 1.7.

For django 1.7, you should use the [cookiecutter recipe](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/tree/1.7.7) (*this is a link to the version for 1.7; the default repository is for django 1.8.*)

I do not know why you have a `heroku.py` file there (this is not part of the template from 2scoops) and is not needed.

The default template from 2scoops assumes the following:

1. You will be using Heroku for deploying your application code.
2. You will be using AWS S3 for deploying your static files.
3. You will be using the default (free) postgresql service from Heroku for your database.
4. You will be using sendgrid (again, from Heroku) to send emails.
5. You will use memcachier (a hosted memcache service, again from Heroku) for your cache.

Make sure that is how you want to get started, because you'll need to setup AWS credentials separately.

Assuming you have started from scratch with the correct template for django 1.7, to launch it on heroku you would have to make sure you **set the appropriate environment variables for Heroku**, to make sure things can connect appropriately. The steps to do this are listed in the [default readme](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/blob/1.7.7/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.repo_name%7D%7D/README.rst#heroku) (which is generated as part of your project).

Please make sure you [follow the guidelines](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/blob/1.7.7/README.rst) to make sure your project is setup correctly.

As a beginner, this may be a lot to digest especially if you are not familiar with django/heroku/AWS.

I suggest instead you follow the [heroku tutorial for django](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django) which is a lot simpler and should get you started immediately.

Comment: I created a heroku.py instead of a staging.py and the same with the requirements file. That's not a worry for me, just the same renamed. I don't know anything about Amazon AWS S3, but I suppose I'm forced now to investigate about it, because everyone is writing about this service, but it's not my intention to use it in production

Comment: I suggest you don't use the template from 2scoops and just follow the heroku tutorial I linked in my answer.

Comment: I will try at least. I like to try and compare the guidance the people give to me and choose my favorite, so I must try each one :-) . The downside is that it will take time.

Comment: I was very busy at work last weeks. I'm trying now with the cookiecutter initial project (https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django), but when doing foreman start web it said         ImproperlyConfigured: 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE' environment variable must be set

I can't find the right value. I've tried with "settings.production", "config.settings.production" and nothing works.